# iScroll keeps scrolling back up (Phonegap)

Tags: javascript, plugins, cordova, iscroll

Program: Eclipse (Phonegap)

Phone: HTC Desire (2.2.2)

I've been playing around with the iscroll plugin for some time now but it seems i can't get it to work. When i test it in both the android emulator and my phone it keeps scrolling back to the the top. Also the LogCat gives the following line:

"Miss a drag as we are waiting for webcore's response for touch down"

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var theScroll;
    function scroll() {
       theScroll = new iScroll('scroll-content', { snap:true, momentum:false, hScrollbar:false, vScrollbar:false});
       setTimeout(function () { theScroll.refresh() }, 0); 
    }
    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', scroll, false);
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">

            <div id="main-content">
                <div id="pages">

                    <div id="map" class="current">  

                    </div>

                    <div id="camera">
                        <button class="camera-control" onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button>

                        <div style="text-align:center; margin:20px 0 0 0;">
                            <img id="cameraPic" src="" style="width:50%; height: 50%;"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="buzz"> 
                           <div id="scroll-content">                
                            <ul id="your-tweets"></ul>
                           </div>                           
                    </div>

                    <div id="info">
                        <p>Informatie Evident</p>
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

I'm populating the list with tweets called in with JSON. Hope somebodey can help!

Comment: Same problem. My workaround is described here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348530/initializing-iscroll-with-phonegap-and-jquery-mobile/18726683#18726683

Answer (score 0):

The full iScroll syntax is: iScroll(element_id, object options).
Options are [here](http://cubiq.org/iscroll).
Among the options we have bounceLock (if set to true the scroller stops bouncing if the content is smaller than the visible area. Default value is false).

Hope this is what you were searching for

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Still when i add the bounceLock it keeps getting back to the top whenever i get my finger of the screen

Comment: Which iScroll you are using,iScroll old version or iScroll4?

Comment: When i give iscroll the option: "snap: true", the scrolling works (tho very buggy) but it doesnt bounce back anymore. You get the "free scrolling" effect. Even when i set the momentum and scrollbar to false (like iScroll recommends) it is still free scrolling

Answer (score 0):

To keep it from scrolling to the top you will need to create the scroll object after the first time you "show" your element. To dynamically add data to this element and maintain a proper scroll with scrolling bars, you can use the following script after each time you add data to the list:

```
    var myScroll = null; //set this initially
    // Check if scroll has been created, if so, destroy and recreate
    if (myScroll != null){
            myScroll.destroy();
        }
        myScroll = new iScroll('call-list', { desktopCompatibility: true, vScroll: true, hScroll: false, hScrollbar: false, lockDirection: true });
```